I can't auto login user after registration in spring boot
when i registrate user my project throws stackOverFlowError, but user is saved to database.I also have registration form. Here is my registration controller:
@PostMapping("/register-user")
public String createUser(@ModelAttribute("user") UserDTO user, RedirectAttributes attributes, HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setRole("ROLE_VIEWER");
        role.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        roles.add(role);

        String rawPassword = user.getPassword();
        String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(hashedPassword);

        service.registerUser(user, roles);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), rawPassword);
        token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        attributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "User registered and logged in successfully.");
        return "redirect:/";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "An error occurred during registration. Please try again.");
        return "redirect:/register";
    }
}

i tried request.login(username, password),
UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByEmail(email);
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);

but user didn't auto login.
i inject AuthenticationManager in SecutirtyConfiguration:
@Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


the reason for stackoverflow is most likely this snippet:
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}

If you look inside of AuthenticationConfiguration class you will see that AuthenticationConfiguration tries to get the bean of AuthenticationManager in order to provide it, for which Spring tried to instantiate it for which AuthenticationConfiguration tries to get it... you get the picture

Here is how you can define authenticationManager instead:
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http, PasswordEncoder passwordEncode, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

    return authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .build();
}

